# Can not install rails 3.0 for Massive Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I am Trying to install rails 3.0 to use with **Massive Record** Gem. But when I am trying to install, the gem rails -v 3.0.0 is installed successfully. But, When I do `rails -v` it shows error :

> /home/mayukh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84:in
>   `setup': undefined method`rubygems' for Bundler:Module
>   (NoMethodError)

Please find the **Ruby, Bundler details** and error details below:[image]

Comment: Does `gem update --system` help?

Comment: This will update the rails verson als, right? I need rails 3.0 only

Comment: It'll just update the `rubygems` gem itself.

Comment: Nope, it says "RubyGems system software updated". But rails -v still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old bundler version that is compatible with neither ruby 2.1 not the version of rubygems that comes with it.

You should also be aware that rails 3.0.x is no longer maintained