# Rails with Hbase. How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hbase

how to integrate Hbase with Rails. 
I came across couple of gems like:

1. **[Massive Records](https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record):** This works with rails 3.0 and ruby 1.9.2, and both of these are pretty old. I could not even install rails 3.0 on my box! [Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170239/can-not-install-rails-3-0-for-massive-record)
2. **[hbase-stargate](https://github.com/greglu/hbase-stargate):** This also look like a very old Gem, and not much docs available

So, is there **any other** good gems which works with latest rails version?
Are not we using Hbase with ROR much?

Comment: which version you are using??

Comment: Massive Records docs said to use rails 3.0. Could not install. Chck this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170239/can-not-install-rails-3-0-for-massive-record

Comment: are you using Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: no, 1.9.2 installation through rvm failed. 2.1.2p95 is my ruby version